# How to design my Mongo database

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database

I got a collection Users, that is name, password, email etc.
Also i got a collection Groups, every group has it's members - array of users.
How should i design my database? I clearly see 2 ways of doing so:
Way 1 (MySQL-like): every user has an _id, so i just put it into the members array and so be it.
Way 2: copy a whole user document inside plus add some fields.
On the MongoDB site they are telling that duplicate data is nothing to worry bcs of the low price of storages. Also they say that we should avoid JOINs on data read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually answer to this question depends on what kind of screens you are designing and what kind of queries you are going to make to fetch data. Lets go through pros and cons of each option which will help you in weighing each option.

**Way 1 :- Putting array of user_ids in group collection**

**Pros**

1) If you have a screen which shows group details of a particular group and list of all members (users_ids) belonging to that group, then one query can fetch all the details needed for this screen and it would be faster too.

**Cons**

1) If in group detail screen, you have to show details of users along with group details, then since mongodb does not provide any joins, you would be fetching user details in a separate query and would be joining both on the client side. This can lead to a impact on performance.

2) If you have a screen which shows user details and all the groups he/she belongs, then you will be searching user_id in user array in group collection. If you are expecting number of members in a group to be very high(millions), then searching inside the array can lead to a huge performance impact.

**Way 2 :- Copy user document inside inside group collection**

Duplicating data is not a problem in Mongodb, but you should have a really good reason for that. Thumb rule should be duplicate data when relationship is 1:few and not 1:many.

**Pros**

1) This approach will save you from joining group and user collection at client side as one query can fetch all the details of group along with its users.

**Cons**

1) Suppose you have a million groups and user_id_1 belongs to 100,000 groups, then whenever you have an update on user_id_1, you will have to update 100,000 documents. This can again lead to huge performance impact.

2) Also if a large number of users subscribe to 1 group, then document size of this group keeps on increasing. In Mongodb [The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/) that means you cannot have a document greater than 16MB, so you cannot add users to a group infinitely. This will limit your functionality.

**Way 3 :- Embed group details in user collection**

**Pros**

1) One query can fetch user details along with all the details of all the groups this user belongs to.

2) If you have are expecting few users in a group, then you will have few group arrays in a user document. This will not exceed 16MB limit.

**Cons**

1) If you are expecting that a user can subscribe to a lot many groups(millions), then user document may exceed 16MB limit.

2) Also if you have very frequent updates in group details then you will have to update the same in many user documents.

You can also go through the following link to get more details about data model design :-
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/

Answer (score 2):

> duplicate data is nothing to worry about

This **is something to worry about** when it comes to updating.  Suppose you have user details nested and duplicated in every document.  What happens when a user changes their name?  You'll have to update every instance of that user in every document.

Be careful to differentiate between data and entities.  A user is an entity, think carefully before duplicating entities as fixing it later could be hard work.

Personally, I'd split them unless you find yourself in a situation where performance is too slow to do the joining in real time.  Then, and only then, consider merging.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you will use data in your application.

If you have more than 2 groups and you will have to search a user in all of the groups, embed the user document within the group (way 2) is not a good idea. So in this case I sugest to use the way 1.

If you have only 2 groups or the user group will be known before your application when doing the query, then use the way 2.

I guess that separating the data is the way to go, since it will be better to direct update, get and delete user data directly.